# How do I change the a border-color on rollover?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm writing a web page that has boxes of text. I want to highlight the text when the mouse rolls over them, by changing the border color, but it hasn't been working.

This is my html code

```
    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
    Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

    <title>main</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="Zolani" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <title>canvas</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="Zolani" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="canvas.css"/>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="canvas.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="title">
        Linear Algebra.
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="box" onmouseover="light()">
            <h1 class="boxtitle"> Matrix </h1>

            <p>
                Here are some matrixes. They're pretty cool, to
                be honest thing!
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class ="box" onmouseover="light()">
            <h1 class="boxtitle"> Subspaces </h1>

            <p>
                Example
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

My css code

```
body { background: #AC00BF }

.title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 800px;
    top: 20px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 4.8em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.box {
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: black;
    margin: 2cm 2cm 2cm 2cm;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 200px;
}

.boxtitle {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Georgia;
}
```

I want to change the border of the div to white when rolled over. I've been trying to use variations of box: hover, but it hasn't worked. I've also used a.box: hover with the  tag implemented, but the div was displaying like a link.

How can I change the the border color of this div to white on hover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `:hover` on `.box` did the work for me:

```
.box:hover{
    border-color: white
}
```

You've to note the order (the following example will not work):

```
.box {
    border-color: black
}

.box:hover{
    border-color: white
}
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/d58K8/)

Comment: He asked for a white color... =))

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use `:hover` css selector?

```
    div.box {
        ...
        border-color: black; (
    }

    div.box:hover {
        border-color: white;
    }
```